# accessing to classmethod raise arguments count error in cython

Tags: python, cython

I have a python `.py` file and move all cython directives to a same name `.pxd` file.

`mod_a.py:`

```py
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def simple_method(cls, param1):
        return param1 * 2

class B(object):
    def method(self):
        return A.simple_method(1) # <-- this line
```

`mod_a.pxd:`

```
cdef class A:
    cdef simple_method(cls, param1)
```

`mod_b.py:`

```
from mod_a import B
b=B()
b.method()
```

supposed that the `simple_method` as a classmethod can be called from `A` and it is working in pure python. but when cythonize the `mod_a` the compiler raise an error on the `A.simple_method(1)` with this error message:

```
mod_a.py:9:24: Call with wrong number of arguments (expected 2, got 1)
```

Why it happened? and what to do?
thanks.

Using:
Python 2.7.6
Cython 0.21.2

here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/wtayyeb/d563d26afc65d6e0eda1/)

Comment: I'm not sure cdef classmethods are supported.  [This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cython-users/FLHiLzzKqj4/3PeNLiInWdsJ) says they're not, although that was a while ago so there could be newer news.

Comment: @BrenBarn thanks. but the thread is about calling classmethod on an instance. I call it on the class itself

Comment: No, the thread gives calling classmethod on an instance as a *reason* why cdef classmethods are not (yet) implemented.  The messages say that cdef classmethods are not allowed.

Comment: ok, currently i move the method out of class and attach it as unbounded method to class. just as dirty as it can. to solve my problem. but I still wait to better answer.